# How to get the correct total number of orders in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I've noticed that there are several ways to get the total number of orders in Magento, using getSize(), for loop, or count(), however, they provide different results within the same time range.
I'd like to know what is the best way to get the correct total number of orders in Magento, and what is the difference between getSize(), for loop and count() when calculating the number of orders. Below is the code I used for testing between getSize() and for loop.

```
//get order total amount
$OrdersAmount_completed = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
        'from' => $timefrom,
        'to' => $timeto,))
      // ->getSize()  //this generates a difference result with $num_completed
    ;
foreach ($OrdersAmount_completed as $order_completed)
{
    $num_completed++; 
}
```

Comment: When you do `getSize` or `count` do you get a `0`? I think i remember these being lazy loaded within collection so `getSize` and `count` would actually be the number fetched into the collection not the records in the DB, unless you had looped over all the records first. However, if this is the case i seem to remember a call you could make to load up all the result without looping... i could be mistaken its been a few months since my last Mage project.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've noticed that using getSize and count gives me the same incorrect amount of orders (less than the actual amount) compare to the result in Magento backend > Report. The foreach loop is closer to the actual amount, but still incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally get Size will always give you proper count. If you get into details, any getCollection() we refer to collection.php inside model/mysql folder.

Inside magento, collection.php extends `Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract` which extends `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` which extends `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`

In Varien_Data_Collection_Db, we have getSize() function which is :

```
<?php 
  public function getSize()
{
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $this->_totalRecords = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}

public function getSelectCountSql()
{
    $this->_renderFilters();

    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

    $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');

    return $countSelect;
}
?>
```

We can see, it is getting all the count from database depending upon the query.

getSize() will only fetch the count from database. If we get all collection and execute foreach, it is going to fetch all order objects which can be a huge query and also load on the database bandwidth. It is hence, not advisable to do so. :)

Comment: Thank you @Blastfreak! I'm asking this because I noticed that using getSize() and count() gives me the same incorrect amount of orders (less than the actual amount) compare to the result in Magento backend > Report. The foreach loop is closer to the actual amount, but still incorrect. I thought it might have something to do with the system time, but I checked on that as well. Not sure which part of data is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this one out. It's caused by time zone difference:

```
//get Magento time zone
echo "Magento System time:".date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()));
//get server time zone 
$timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
echo "The current server timezone is: " . $timezone;
```

I've found the server time is using UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), and for Magento it's using something different.